# My code is fully functioning in CLion but I get an error in repl.it

Tags: c, replit

Can someone please help me? I am new to C Programming and I am getting a compile issue in repl.it that is not appearing when I run my code in CLion.

The error is: 
exit status -1

main.c:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
 12
 ^~

```
/*
 * Description: This is a multiplication problem generator, for children.
 * Created By: Michael Isenhour
 * Date Written: June 6th, 2018
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int generateRandomNumber();
void askQuestion(int, int);

int main(void) {
    srand(1712);
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < 10) {
        int randomlyGeneratedFirstNumber = generateRandomNumber();
        int randomlyGeneratedSecondNumber = generateRandomNumber();
        int answer = randomlyGeneratedFirstNumber * randomlyGeneratedSecondNumber;
        int userAnswer;
        askQuestion(randomlyGeneratedFirstNumber, randomlyGeneratedSecondNumber);
        scanf("%d", &userAnswer);

        while (userAnswer != answer) {
            puts("No, Please try again");
            askQuestion(randomlyGeneratedFirstNumber, randomlyGeneratedSecondNumber);
            scanf("%d", &userAnswer);
        }

        puts("Very Good");
        counter++;

    }
    return 0;
}

int generateRandomNumber() {
    int result;
    result = 1 + (rand() % 9);
    return result;
}

void askQuestion(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
    printf("How much is %d times %d\n", firstNumber, secondNumber);
}
```

Comment: [Could not reproduce](https://repl.it/repls/WigglyGoldenConditional). I also don't see any numeric constant 12, especially not on line 1.

Comment: I copy pasted your code to repl.it, it doesn't give the errors you post. The code compiles fine

Comment: That's so weird, I keep getting an error. Here is a screenshot of my error. https://ibb.co/dUywk8

Comment: Your screenshot shows your program is not running (The "Run" button is present, you need to press it.), and you are writing into the repl window. The website will apparently try to compile anything you write into that window as C code. So when you type "12", the web site saves what you typed in a file called main.c and tries to compile it

Comment: Yeah Daniel it seems to work fine on your repl.it...when I cut and paste to my repl.it the error occurs again though. Im stumped.

Comment: nos, as soon as I press it i get an exit status -1 message, BUT then it says the "How much is 2 times 6" so it has to be running my code, just not sure whats up. This is a screenshot of what I get as soon as I press run. https://ibb.co/nvEK58

Comment: when writing a prototype for a function that takes no parameters, place `void` between the parens.  Note: the `void` is not needed in the actual function signature.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: these 'scattered' statements; `int counter = 0;` and `while (counter < 10)` and `counter++;`  would be much better written as: `#define MAX_TRIES 10`  and `for( int counter=0; counter< MAX_TRIES; counter++ ) {...}`

Comment: regarding: `srand(1712);` This will always produce the same sequence of random numbers. Suggest using: `#include <time.h>` and `srand( (unsigned) time( NULL ) );`